# Can I use the leftover pickling brine?

Tags: food-safety

I have some leftover brine that was leftover from making canned pickles, it was heated up to put in the canned pickles to make them. Can I use this brine again to make more canned pickles? The brine never touched the pickles or anything else.

Comment: If the brine is no more than 24 hours, go for it, if not toss.  I had a similar question, I believe a while back.  You could reheat the brine, let it cool then put the pickles in it.  If this is the case 48 hours max, but again, reheat, cool then put the pickles in.  My dad used my brine over and over again without doing anything to it once he ate my pickled veges and almost hit 96, but I really don't suggest it.  24 hours, use the brine more than 24 less the 48 reboil, cool, pickle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reusing pickle brine](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/23539/reusing-pickle-brine)

Comment: disagree on the dupe - that is for brine that is quite old and had pickles in it. This is for salty and/or vinegary water that was heated up and then cooled. It doesn't have the same risks as brine that has had pickles, herbs, spices etc in it for ages and been exposed to air repeatedly.

Comment: Definitely a dupe of [this](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/54628/using-unused-pickling-juice/54655#54655).  Nutshell: probably safe for fridge pickles if it is just the brine (water, salt, sugar, vinegar).  Heating it more than once may make it not shelf-stable.  I would assume used pickle juice may be ok for quick fridge pickles once or twice, but you should probably just filter it and use it for dressings or marinades.

Comment: What is in the brine?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure any of the above have read your question completely.  You are asking; can you store extra brine that you made but was not used in your pickling process.  I do this systematically when my  Green Beans are going crazy.  I mix up extra brine and store it in the refrigerator for up to 2 weeks.  The brine is simple pickling salt, water and white vinegar.  Then I can use it incrementally as my produce comes in. Saves me a few steps by simply reheating premixed brine instead of making it each time.  I like this approach because it allows me to put up a few pints at a time while the beans are fresh.  Have never had a problem with my Dilly Beans.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if I comprehend correctly, it was part of the brine solution you heated, but it was not actually used in pickling.  There is (arguably) some concern with reuse pickled liquids, on the basis of potential levels of bacteria.

Personally, I have reused pickling solutions - though these have mainly been vinegar solutions based and not brine solutions.  Have yet to delve into natural fermentation 'pickling'.

Comment: You never reuse brine that has been used  on meat

Comment: Veggie brines are ok though